# java.lang.NullPointerException, cant see whats wrong

Tags: java, swing

I have trying to fix this bit of code for ages now and have already posted on here because of another problem! Here is the error i am getting now...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Maze.Map.getMap(Map.java:34)
    at Maze.Board.paint(Board.java:32)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

And here is the code that it is coming from... Sorry for the bad coding but i am a total beginner!

```
package Maze;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Map {
private Scanner m;
private String map[] = new String[14];
private Image floor,
              wall; 

public Map(){

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C://Test//MazeGame//floor.jpg");
    floor = img.getImage();
    img = new ImageIcon("C://Test//MazeGame//wall.jpg");
    wall = img.getImage();

    openFile();
    readFile();
    closeFile();
}

public Image getFloor(){
    return floor;
}
public Image getWall(){
    return wall;
}

public String getMap(int x, int y){
    String index = map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
    return index;
}

public void openFile(){

    try{
    m = new Scanner(new File("C://Test//MazeGame//Map.txt"));
    }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("Error Loading Map!");
    }
}

public void readFile(){        
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
       while(m.hasNext()){
          map[i] = m.next();
       }
   }
 }


public void closeFile(){
    m.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not have initialized your map array. This line allocates space for 14 String(s) it doesn't initialize them to a value (that is they default to null).

```
String map[] = new String[14]; // <-- 14 Null strings.
```

The `readFile` method should look something like this

```
public void readFile(){        
  for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
    if (! m.hasNext()) {
      // Alert the user!
      System.err.println("The map file stopped at entry: " + i);
      break;
    }
    map[i] = m.next();
  }
  // to help in debugging.
  System.out.println("The map is: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(map));
}
```

If you're still having problems I'd add some messaging to `getMap` with something like this

```
public String getMap(int x, int y) {
  System.out.printf("getMap('%d', '%d')\n", x, y);
  if (map != null && map[y] != null) {
    String index = map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
    return index;
  }
  System.out.println("Returning null");
  return null;
}
```

Comment: So how do i initialize them to a value? Sorry if this is a stupid question! :-)

Comment: @SeanCoyne Update your `readFile`, I've edited my answer with one approach.

Comment: It has came up with a NPE again :-/

Comment: @SeanCoyne Do you have a debugger? I think you're going to need to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Still totally stuck! i watching a tutorial and i have done everything they have done but mine isn't working!

Comment: @SeanCoyne Edited to add a map print, what value is `y`?

Answer (score 3):

`map[y]` is `null`, that's why you are getting this exception. When you initialize an array, it allocates the size and all the positions (indexes) are `null`. You need to make all the indexes to refer to an object of the declared array type. i.e here it would be `String`

Comment: Does what mean it cant find the file?

Comment: it means the `index` 'y' in `map String array` is `null`. it doesn't have any String reference

Answer (score 0):

You have not populated the `map` array with `String` values.

```
for(int i = 0;i<map.length;i++){
map[i] = "somevalue";
}
```

*Reason for exception*

`map[y]` gives `null` in your case and so on doing `null.substring()` you get a NPE.

Try debugging to find out what the actual value of `y` is when you get a NPE. Or put a `System.out.println("Value of y is" + y);` to find out at which index you get a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause is some how, you are calling `getMap()` method with an index (`y`), such that `map[y]` becomes `null`. This can be because of binding the `map` array only having `14` values! recheck your `readFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You just define the String array:
private String map[] = new String[14];

But you did not initialize elements in this String Array, map[0], map[1],...